# What is considered to be a good silhouette score?

Tags: python, k-means

I am currently doing some clustering based on words embeddings, and I am using some methods (elbow and David-Boulding) to determine the optimal number of clusters I should consider. In addition, I consider the silhouette measure. If I understood it correctly, it is a measure of the correct match of the data with the correct cluster, ranging from - 1 (mismatch) to 1 (correct match).

Using kmeans clustering, I obtain a silhouette score oscillating between 0.5 and 0.55. So according to the silhouette, the elbow method (that is a bit too smooth but it might because I have a lot of data) and the David-Bouldin index, I should consider 5 clusters. However, I don't know if 0.5 can be considered as a good score? I added the graphs of the different measures I made, the function I used to generate them (found online) as well as the clustering obtained.

```
def check_clustering(X, K):
    sse,db,slc = {}, {}, {}
    for k in range(2, K):
        # seed of 10 for reproducibility.
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=1000,random_state=SEED).fit(X)
        if k == 3: labels = kmeans.labels_
        clusters = kmeans.labels_
        sse[k] = kmeans.inertia_ # Inertia: Sum of distances of samples to their closest cluster center
        db[k] = davies_bouldin_score(X,clusters)
        slc[k] = silhouette_score(X,clusters)


    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    plt.plot(list(sse.keys()), list(sse.values()))
    plt.xlabel("Number of cluster")
    plt.ylabel("SSE")
    plt.show()

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    plt.plot(list(db.keys()), list(db.values()))
    plt.xlabel("Number of cluster")
    plt.ylabel("Davies-Bouldin values")
    plt.show()

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    plt.plot(list(slc.keys()), list(slc.values()))
    plt.xlabel("Number of cluster")
    plt.ylabel("Silhouette score")
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

I am quite new to k-means clustering and mainly followed online tutorials. Can somebody tell me if the scores obtained through the different measures (but mostly silhouette's) seem correct?

Thank you for your answer.

(Also, there is a subsidiary question but I find the shape of the clusters a bit weird (I would expect them to be more fragmented). Is it a possible shape of clusters? (Note that I used the PCA to reduce the dimensions, so it might be because of that).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it make sense for your data to have 5 clusters?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am using movies reviews and trying to cluster them according to the embedding of the words used in these reviews (so normally the words used to describe a action movie would be different than a horror movie). 5 clusters seems definitely a good number. I am just doubtful on the score obtained as well as the cluster's shape that are really close to each others.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to interpret your silhouette plot. More common form of silhouette plot is essentially a bar plot grouped by cluster where the height/length of each of bars is the silhouette score of the particular data point. This way you can see how well each of the points fits in its cluster. You can't get any useful information like this in your plot.

Comment: For example, check out this article on using silhouette plots  from scikit-learn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html

Comment: Such the one found here (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html) ? I found the plot function online but if you know a more efficient, it would be awesom.

Comment: Oh, aha you linked the same as mine. I'll check this one out, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just searched this myself.

A silhouette score of one means each data point is unlikely to be assigned to another cluster.

A score close to zero means each data point could be easily assigned to another cluster

A score close to -1 means the datapoint is misclassified.

Based on these assumptions, I'd say 0.55 is still informative though not definitive and therefore you would need additional analysis to make any assertions based on your data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).